# What are the two spikes on an HP 2013 Ultraslim docking station?

Tags: laptop, docking-station, hp-elitebook

The docking station I have for my laptop had these two little plastic spikes with a spring loaded metal tip poking up next to the latches that hold the laptop in place. The dock fell off the table with the computer in place and they broke off. What is their purpose? The docking station still seems to work without them.

Comment: As mentioned by John below they are to aid alignment. Their primary reason for existing will be to pull the laptop into the correct position to minimise stress on the connector itself when you are connecting it and to act as the points where movement stresses are transferred between the dock and your laptop when you shift it slightly or knock it. They will help make sure that the connectors on your dock and laptop survive for as long as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spikes are there to ensure exact alignment of the electrical connectors dock and laptop.

If you can align the connectors properly and it works, you may get by for a while without replacing the dock (not fixable the way it is).

My suggestion:  Replace the dock. Better for the longer term.